# Dillon and his homeboys go to the movies, yet they pay for only one ticket

Tags: lateral-thinking

Dillon and his homeboys go to a theater to see *Sex Lives of the Potato Men*, just for the price of one ticket. There are no special offers or discounts or any other thing like that. You must buy, have the ticket and show the ticket to ticket checker person, to see the respective movie. No back entrances or alternative entrances. Sneaking in is not possible.

How did Dillon and his homeboys watched the movie by just paying for one ticket?

Answer (score 4):

I think this puzzle, as written, is going to generate a lot of valid answers...

That being said, here's my thought:

> Dillon has no friends; thus, only he needs to purchase a ticket.

Alternatively,

> Dillon's friends are fish heads; according to [Barnes and Barnes' song](https://genius.com/Barnes-and-barnes-fish-heads-lyrics), then, when taking them to a movie, one doesn't have to pay to get them in!

Comment: If you think a question is under-specified, please vote to put it on hold until further details are given instead of answering.

Comment: Svfu urnqf, svfu urnqf, ebyl cbyl svfu urnqf

Comment: Svfu urnqf, svfu urnqf rng gurz hc, lhzz

Answer (score 4):

I found on Wikipedia that

> There is an album called Homeboys by a band called Adam Again.

And so,

> Dillon could have walked in with the album in his hand, which only necessitates one ticket, and allows him to go with his "Homeboys".

An alternative answer:

> There is no mention of the tickets being for a specific showing (timing), so maybe the homeboys could go 1-by-1, reusing the same ticket when each one has finished watching the movie and coming out, although it could take quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

> Drive in theatre...they were together in the car

Comment: I put the answer in a spoiler tag, but frankly that's exactly all there is. A short answer like this could be just a comment, and if you think that there is no call for a longer, more elaborated answer, the question itself is probably not that great.

Comment: I am new here and not sure of the difference between an answer and a comment. My bad. will see how it goes. thanks.

Comment: @Xenocacia, Surendar shouldn't answer in comments, per [Help Page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), there really wasn't much else to say to justify his answer, the reasoning is fairly intuitive...

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman: I know it doesn't look right in the comments either, and if an answer can be so easily arrived at with intuitive reasoning, the problem is usually the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know about Dillon's homeboys...

> Dillon's homeboys could be the movie theater projectionists and ushers. If they are, only Dillon would need a ticket, because his friends would already be working inside the theater and watching the movie.

Answer (score 1):

> Dillon's homeboys work for the cinema.

Or

> Dillon's homeboys are all in his head.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this answer is different from @Retro's and mine, below?

Answer (score 0):

If "Sex Lives of the Potato Men" really is one of the worst films ever (as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_Lives_of_the_Potato_Men) article) then you could expect a lot of people to leave the theater early. So the people leaving could have passed their tickets on to Dillon's homeboys.